# rpart doesn't build a full tree – problems with cp?

Tags: r, rpart, cart-analysis

I'm trying to build a full tree by setting control to `rpart.control(minsplit=2, minbucket = 1,cp=0)`, but it doesn't work. I think the reason may be that the summary tree with 4 splits has `cp` = 0, but this tree isn't full, so its `cp` should be > 0.
I also checked the data, and more splits are possible. 
Here is my code:

```
#################
# libraries #####
library(datasets)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
##################
# preparing data #
titanic_obs=c()
for (cl in c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew")) {
  for (se in c("Male","Female")) {
    for (ag in c("Child","Adult")) {
      for (sur in c("Yes","No")) {
        titanic_obs = rbind(titanic_obs,matrix(rep(c(cl,se,ag,sur),length.out=4*Titanic[cl,se,ag,sur]),ncol=4,byrow=T))    
      }
    }
  }
}

colnames(titanic_obs)= c("Class", "Sex", "Age","Survived")
titanic_data = data.frame(titanic_obs)
summary(titanic_data) 
#################
# fitting model #
titanic_rpart = rpart(Survived ~ Sex + Age + Class,
                  data = titanic_data,method="class",
                  control=rpart.control(minsplit=2, minbucket = 1,cp=0))
#################
# checking ######
summary(titanic_rpart)
prp(titanic_rpart, extra=1, uniform=F, branch=1, yesno=F, border.col=0, xsep="/")
#################
# data ##########
adult_men = titanic_data[titanic_data$Sex=="Male" & titanic_data$Age=="Adult",]
all_am = table(adult_men$Class)
    survived_am = table(adult_men[adult_men$Survived=="Yes",]$Class)
survived_am/all_am
```

Comment: Probably a machine tolerance issue with some extremely small cp values. Try setting `cp = -1` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in a comment to this question, setting `cp=-1` will build the full tree.

Answer (score -1):

Cannot check right now, but I seem to recall that setting cp=0.000001 or a similarly small
number solved the issue for me at some point. Also notice that there are parameters like minsplit and minbucket that may hinder the growth of the tree, so you might want to set appropriate values for those also.

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see that the OP has set cp smaller than you recommend, and also set minsplit and minbucket appropriately, and those things didn't work.